# Can not connect my Azure AppService to VNet

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azureportal

I have a problem connecting my Azure AppService to a new subnet created.
My AppService is upgraded to PremiumV2 plan. When trying to setup subnet via VNet Integration I can see the VNet as well as newly created Subnet in selection drop down, but getting an error

`The request timed out. Diagnostic information: timestamp 'xxxxx', subscription id '',  tracking id 'xxxxx', request correlation id 'xxxxx'.`

If I change my AppService plan to another PremiumV2 everything works fine (newly created subnet has no other applications using it).
Maybe someone has any ideas what could be wrong since I looked at [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration#limitations) defined by Microsoft and there should be no problem with those.

Comment: This usually happens with regional vnet, a dedicated subnet have to be integrated with the service.
Try creating a dedicated subnet for your app service and also make sure 'WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE'
is set to False.

Comment: Have you set it to false, did it work?